# React Router – replicate <Link /> in fetched html <a>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

My project has a CMS system, which stores blocks in HTML format. Links in this HTML link to the existing routes, which are handled by ReactRouter. I need to somehow overwrite `/category/123` of HTML's native link, in order to use ReactRouter build-in transition, not Native one (which kind'a reloads the page).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use library to parse the native HTML to React elements. In addition, you can replace all the `a` tags with React Router `Link`. Check:
[html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser)